# How to pass a value to orderBy in queryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a table with some strings, like

```
id| value
  |
1 | test1
2 | test2
3 | testLASTONE
4 | test4
5 | test5
```

and I want **testLASTONE** to be at the end of the list when I execute a select all. In sql I would use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value = 'testLASTONE' ASC, value;
```

how can I translate this in query builder given that orderBy and addOrderBy only take the field name as first parameter (basically the '=' char throws an error)?

Comment: Maybe you can use the add() method of doctorine's query builder to set a custom orderBy statement? (https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.9.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L702)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = 'value' ORDER BY column_name ASC;
```

For Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE value = 'testLASTONE' ORDER BY value ASC;
```

Comment: The query works for the user, the problem he has is how to accomplish this query with doctorine's query builder.